# Rolling correlation that includes all previous values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compute the correlation between two time series columns. I know that I can do this to get a singular r value:

```
df['a'].corr(df['b'])
```

However, I want to get the r value of the correlation between all previous and current values. I know pandas has prebuilt `rolling` functions, but these only include the specified window as history. Is there a prebuilt pandas way to do this?

For example:

```
a     b
1     4
1     4
2     3
3     2
4     1
5     0
1     6
```

`df['a'].corr(df['b'])` returns `-1`. What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
a     b    corr
1     4    np.nan   
1     4    np.nan
2     3    -1
3     2    -1
4     1    -1
5     0    -1
1     6    -.93
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [expanding corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.corr.html#pandas-core-window-expanding-expanding-corr):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 1},
    'b': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 6}
})

df['corr'] = df['a'].expanding().corr(df['b'])

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   a  b      corr
0  1  4       NaN
1  1  4       NaN
2  2  3 -1.000000
3  3  2 -1.000000
4  4  1 -1.000000
5  5  0 -1.000000
6  1  6 -0.939664
```